# Extend Option object with additional field in react-select

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

I want to add additional field to default option object, I am trying to implement dropdown select with icon inside. I was able to fully implement working select but struggle to get correct typescript types.

Here is simplified example.

```
export interface BaseItemProps {
    value: string;
    label: string;
}

interface IconDropdownItemProps extends BaseItemProps {
    iconCode: string;
}

const IconFieldOption = (props: OptionProps<IconDropdownItemProps, false>): ReactElement => {
    const { data } = props;
    return (
        <components.Option {...props}>
            <IconField {...data} />
        </components.Option>
    );
};



const IconDropdown = (props: Omit<SelectProps, 'components'>,): ReactElement => {
    const { defaultLocale } = props;

    return (
        <Dropdown
            {...props}
            options={SupportedLanguages}
            components={{ Option: IconField }}
        />
    );
};
```

The error that I have:

> Type '(props: OptionProps<IconDropdownItemProps, false>) => ReactElement' is not assignable to >type 'ComponentType<OptionProps<{ label: string; value: string; }, false, GroupTypeBase<{ >label: string; value: string; }>>> | undefined'.

> Property 'iconCode' is missing in type '{ label: string; value: string; }' but required in type >'IconDropdownItemProps

How I should extend this?